# Get SamAccountname using DisplayName in Active Directory

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I need vbscript that will do an LDAP query using a displayname, and retrieve the SamAccountName for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

strDomainName = "dc=YOURDOMAIN,dc=com"
strUserCN = "FIRSTNAME LASTNAME"

objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://" & strDomainName & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(cn=" & strUserCN & "));samAccountName;subtree"

Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

If Not objRecordset.EOF Then
    WScript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("samAccountName")
End If

objConnection.Close
Set objRecordSet = Nothing
Set objConnection = Nothing
Set objCommand = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Great script ( and thankyou ) but at the moment only shows the first result in the recordset - the displaying the output bit needs to something more like this:

```
DO until objRecordset.EOF = TRUE

    WScript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("samAccountName")
    objRecordSet.MoveNext

Loop
```